# Basic Python calculator help: print cannot divide by 0

Tags: python

I'm asked to code a calculator in python and here is what I have that works:

```
operation = input("please input your operation (+,-,*,/): ")
number_1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: ")) 
number_2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: ")) 

if operation == '+': 
    print("result: ",(number_1 + number_2)) 

elif operation == '-': 
    print("result: ",(number_1 - number_2)) 

elif operation == '*': 
    print("result: ",(number_1 * number_2)) 

elif operation == '/':
    print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2))

else: 
    print("Invalid input")
```

Now, I just want to add a qualifier that if the user inputs a 0 as "number_2", the program prints "Error! Cannot divide by 0!!!"

Comment: Clearly you know how to use `if` statements and the `print` function, so what's the problem?

Comment: why not run, catch ZeroDivide or whatever it’s called and then display your message?.  Ask for Forgiveness, not Permission is a general Python community programming trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code from :

```
operation = input("please input your operation (+,-,*,/): ")
number_1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: ")) 
number_2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: ")) 

if operation == '+': 
print("result: ",(number_1 + number_2)) 

elif operation == '-': 
print("result: ",(number_1 - number_2)) 

elif operation == '*': 
print("result: ",(number_1 * number_2)) 

elif operation == '/':
print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2))

else: 
print("Invalid input")
```

To:

```
operation = input("please input your operation (+,-,*,/): ")
number_1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: ")) 
number_2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: ")) 

if operation == '+': 
print("result: ",(number_1 + number_2)) 

elif operation == '-': 
print("result: ",(number_1 - number_2)) 

elif operation == '*': 
print("result: ",(number_1 * number_2)) 

elif operation == '/':
   if number_2 == 0 :
      print ("Error! Cannot divide by 0!!!")
   else:
      print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2))

else: 
print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! with the exception of a "expected indented block" error?? it worked flawlessly! just had to throw a tab in there :)

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to just check if `number_2` contains zero before performing the calculation:

```
elif operation == '/':
    if number_2 != 0:
        print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2))
    else:
        print("Cannot divide by 0")
```

An alternative would be to catch the `ZeroDivisionError` that is thrown whenever you try to divide by `0`:

```
elif operation == '/':
    try:
        print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Cannot divide by 0")
```

Comment: Yes! I saw something similar on here after trying to do my due-diligence before asking the question but it gave me syntax errors when I tried. Your suggestion, however, has solved it completely! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

nest a `if` in your `'/'` judgement code segment.

```
operation = input("please input your operation (+,-,*,/): ")
number_1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: ")) 
number_2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: ")) 

if operation == '+': 
    print("result: ",(number_1 + number_2)) 

elif operation == '-': 
    print("result: ",(number_1 - number_2)) 

elif operation == '*': 
    print("result: ",(number_1 * number_2)) 

elif operation == '/':
    if number_2 == 0:
        print("Error! Cannot divide by 0!!!")
    else:
        print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2))

else: 
    print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't divide by 0.

But solve this using exception handling [Python exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

[see here why can't divide by zero](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311155/will-a-computer-attempt-to-divide-by-zero)

```
operation = input("please input your operation (+,-,*,/): ")
number_1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
number_2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
try:
    if operation == '+':
       print("result: ",(number_1 + number_2)) 
    elif operation == '-':
       print("result: ",(number_1 - number_2))
    elif operation == '*': 
       print("result: ",(number_1 * number_2)) 
    elif operation == '/':
       print("result: ",(number_1 / number_2)) 
    else:
       print("Invalid input")
except ZeroDivisionError:
       print ("You can't enter number_2 Zero !!!")
```